# Java Regex Case Insensitive with German Umlaut

Tags: java, regex

I want to locate/replace a word in a text. The word example is "TÜTÜ". Here is the code:

```
    final String regexX = "TÜTÜ";
    final String string = "dsad dasdasd dasd \n"
            + "dsds\n"
            + " dd \n"
            + "sadsd.sdasd. \n"
            + " universität \n"
            + " blö \n"
            + " Blö\n"
            + " ble\n"
            + "üeee \n"
            + " Wörterbuch \n"
            + "Das gute alte Tütü wird";
    final String subst = "";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexX, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    final Matcher matcherX = pattern.matcher(string);

    final String result = matcherX.replaceAll(subst);

    System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

The result is, that nothing gets replaced. This is actually copied code from regex101.com where the german TÜTÜ is also not recognised.  Is it true that case insensitivity does not work for German "Umlaute" or is there a way to make it work?

Comment: marked as duplicate... nice. if we are talking regex something like this might work: `(?i)(*TÜTÜ*)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexX, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

You need to add [Pattern.UNICODE_CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE), otherwise only US-ASCII charset is used for CASE_INSENSITIVE:

> Enables Unicode-aware case folding. When this flag is specified then
>   case-insensitive matching, when enabled by the CASE_INSENSITIVE flag,
>   is done in a manner consistent with the Unicode Standard. By default,
>   case-insensitive matching assumes that only characters in the US-ASCII
>   charset are being matched.
>
> Unicode-aware case folding can also be enabled via the embedded flag
>   expression (?u).
>
> Specifying this flag may impose a performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks, indeed there is a impact on performance.